# Is there a way to turn off messages from zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am using zookeeper successfully. It keeps printing status updates and warnings to the shell, which is actually making it harder to debug my program (which is not working as well as zookeeper). Is there an easy way to turn that off in zookeeper without going into the source? Or is there a way to run a java program so that only the executing program gets to print to the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 'logging' chapter of [Zookeeper administrator's guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_logging) what you actually want?

ZooKeeper uses `log4j` so it is pretty standard logging approach with lot of configuration flexibility available.

Answer (score 0):

By default zookeeper emits INFO or higher severity level messages and it uses log4j for logging. So define logging level to a higher severity in your log4j.properties (assuming you provided the path to the .properties or it's in the working directory)

Answer (score 0):

there is a similar post on avoiding ZooKeeper log messages - like this:

```
zoo_set_log_stream(fopen("NULL", "w"));
```

This will turn of all output from ZooKeeper